# instagram block drupal 7 low resolution images

Tags: drupal-7, instagram

I am using the Instagram block module on a drupal 7 site.  It seems like the images are loading as low resolution, but I would like them to load at a higher resolution.  Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: Show code. The answer lies in the Instagram API - you can specify the resolutions, there  -

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Which code are you looking for?  the instagram_block.lib.php code or the instagram-block-iamge.tpl.php code?  Sorry I am new to using the Instagram Block Module

Answer (score 0):

This is under the block's options -

If you dig into `instagram_block.module` - you'll see that it does specify `$image_options` - which allows you to modify the image-resolution that is returned...

So, poke around the admin GUI a bit more, and you'll find what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're not going mad - there's a bug in the module you're using. Apply this patch (not yet committed to the current release, as of 24th Nov 15):

https://www.drupal.org/node/2387363#comment-9404315